# Domain/theme name suddenly appearing in all links

Tags: uri, navigation

I noticed that all my in-site links now have my domain/theme name inserted after the domain. For example:

www.mydomain.com/mydomain/calendar
www.mydomain/com/mydomain/events

It used to be:

www.mydomain.com/calendar
www.mydomain/com/events

The new links still work, but they don't look very clean.

I don't know what is causing this or where to begin troubleshooting. I don't see anything in the Path module's patterns that would cause this. Should I be looking for a cause in .htaccess or settings.php (.htaccess hasn't been touched in months.)?

Could it be a module? Here's what currently enabled:

```
# drush pm-list --type=Module --status=enabled
 Package                      Name                                                    Version
 Administration               Administration menu (admin_menu)                        7.x-3.0-rc4
 Administration               Administration menu Toolbar style (admin_menu_toolbar)  7.x-3.0-rc4
 Chaos tool suite             Chaos tools (ctools)                                    7.x-1.4
 Chaos tool suite             Custom content panes (ctools_custom_content)            7.x-1.4
 Chaos tool suite             Page manager (page_manager)                             7.x-1.4
 Commerce                     Cart (commerce_cart)                                    7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Checkout (commerce_checkout)                            7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Commerce (commerce)                                     7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Commerce UI (commerce_ui)                               7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Customer (commerce_customer)                            7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Line Item (commerce_line_item)                          7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Order (commerce_order)                                  7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Payment (commerce_payment)                              7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Price (commerce_price)                                  7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Product (commerce_product)                              7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Product Pricing (commerce_product_pricing)              7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Product Reference (commerce_product_reference)          7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Tax (commerce_tax)                                      7.x-1.10
 Commerce                     Tax UI (commerce_tax_ui)                                7.x-1.10
 Commerce (payment)           First Data Global Gateway e4 (commerce_firstdata_gge4)  7.x-1.0
 Commerce (payment)           First Data Global Gateway e4 Hosted Payment Pages       7.x-1.0
                              (commerce_firstdata_gge4_hpp)
 Contact Forms                Contact Forms (contact_forms)                           7.x-1.8
 Core                         Block (block)                                           7.32
 Core                         Blog (blog)                                             7.32
 Core                         Contact (contact)                                       7.32
 Core                         Database logging (dblog)                                7.32
 Core                         Field (field)                                           7.32
 Core                         Field SQL storage (field_sql_storage)                   7.32
 Core                         File (file)                                             7.32
 Core                         Filter (filter)                                         7.32
 Core                         Image (image)                                           7.32
 Core                         List (list)                                             7.32
 Core                         Menu (menu)                                             7.32
 Core                         Node (node)                                             7.32
 Core                         Number (number)                                         7.32
 Core                         Options (options)                                       7.32
 Core                         Path (path)                                             7.32
 Core                         PHP filter (php)                                        7.32
 Core                         Search (search)                                         7.32
 Core                         System (system)                                         7.32
 Core                         Taxonomy (taxonomy)                                     7.32
 Core                         Text (text)                                             7.32
 Core                         Update manager (update)                                 7.32
 Core                         User (user)                                             7.32
 Date/Time                    Date (date)                                             7.x-2.8
 Date/Time                    Date All Day (date_all_day)                             7.x-2.8
 Date/Time                    Date API (date_api)                                     7.x-2.8
 Date/Time                    Date Popup (date_popup)                                 7.x-2.8
 Date/Time                    Date Repeat API (date_repeat)                           7.x-2.8
 Date/Time                    Date Repeat Field (date_repeat_field)                   7.x-2.8
 Date/Time                    Date Tools (date_tools)                                 7.x-2.8
 Date/Time                    Date Views (date_views)                                 7.x-2.8
 Drupal for Facebook          Facebook API (fb)                                       7.x-3.4
 Drupal for Facebook          Facebook Apps (fb_app)                                  7.x-3.4
 Features                     Features (features)                                     7.x-2.2
 Features extra               FE Block (fe_block)                                     7.x-1.0-beta1
 Feeds                        Feeds (feeds)                                           7.x-2.0-alpha8
 Feeds                        Feeds Admin UI (feeds_ui)                               7.x-2.0-alpha8
 Feeds                        Feeds Import (feeds_import)                             7.x-2.0-alpha8
 Feeds                        Feeds XPath Parser (feeds_xpathparser)                  7.x-1.0-beta4
 Fields                       Address Field (addressfield)                            7.x-1.0-beta5
 Fields                       Conditional Fields (conditional_fields)                 7.x-3.0-alpha1
 Fields                       Link (link)                                             7.x-1.2
 Flickr                       Flickr (flickr)                                         7.x-1.6
 Flickr                       Flickr Block (flickr_block)                             7.x-1.6
 Flickr                       Flickr Filter (flickr_filter)                           7.x-1.6
 Flickr                       Flickr Sets (flickr_sets)                               7.x-1.6
 OM                           OM Maximenu (om_maximenu)                               7.x-1.44
 Other                        Advanced help (advanced_help)                           7.x-1.1
 Other                        Backup and Migrate (backup_migrate)                     7.x-2.8
 Other                        Entity API (entity)                                     7.x-1.5
 Other                        Entity tokens (entity_token)                            7.x-1.5
 Other                        Image crop (imagefield_crop)                            7.x-1.1
 Other                        Job Scheduler (job_scheduler)                           7.x-2.0-alpha3
 Other                        Job Scheduler Trigger (job_scheduler_trigger)           7.x-2.0-alpha3
 Other                        Menu attributes (menu_attributes)                       7.x-1.0-rc3
 Other                        Module Object Oriented Programming API (moopapi)        7.x-1.2
 Other                        Node clone (clone)                                      7.x-1.0-rc2
 Other                        Pathauto (pathauto)                                     7.x-1.2
 Other                        PDFThumb (pdfthumb)                                     7.x-1.1
 Other                        Redirect (redirect)                                     7.x-1.0-rc1
 Other                        Token (token)                                           7.x-1.5
 Path Breadcrumbs             Path Breadcrumbs (path_breadcrumbs)                     7.x-3.0
 Path Breadcrumbs             Path Breadcrumbs UI (path_breadcrumbs_ui)               7.x-3.0
 Performance and scalability  Boost (boost)                                           7.x-1.0
 Performance and scalability  Cache Expiration (expire)                               7.x-1.0-beta1
 Rules                        Rules (rules)                                           7.x-2.7
 Rules                        Rules UI (rules_admin)                                  7.x-2.7
 SEO                          Metatag (metatag)                                       7.x-1.4
 Spam control                 BOTCHA (botcha)                                         7.x-3.3
 Statistics                   Google Analytics (googleanalytics)                      7.x-1.4
 User interface               CKEditor (ckeditor)                                     7.x-1.16
 User interface               jQuery Update (jquery_update)                           7.x-2.4
 User interface               Lightbox2 (lightbox2)                                   7.x-1.0-beta1
 Views                        Views (views)                                           7.x-3.8
 Views                        Views Bulk Operations (views_bulk_operations)           7.x-3.2
 Views                        Views UI (views_ui)                                     7.x-3.8
 Webform                      Webform (webform)                                       7.x-3.21
 XML sitemap                  XML sitemap (xmlsitemap)                                7.x-2.0
 XML sitemap                  XML sitemap menu (xmlsitemap_menu)                      7.x-2.0
 XML sitemap                  XML sitemap node (xmlsitemap_node)                      7.x-2.0
```

Comment: Check your settings file and see if you're setting $base_path to something out of the ordinary.

Comment: @Darvanen I assume you mean $base_url? That was commented out. Enabling it with my URL fixed the issue. There is definitely an underlying issue with this site's setup, because I go back-and-forth with enabling and disabling $base_url whenever there's a strange problem that I can't find any solution to. Most of the time, changing $base_url (uncommenting if it's commented out, or commenting out if it's enabled) fixes the strange problems. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide an answer to your own question and then check it as the accepted answer. I think that is the proper way in StackExchange software/commmunities to indicate a question has been [SOLVED].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$base_url in settings.php was disabled; enabling it with my domain as the value seems to have resolved to problem.

Answer (score 0):

happend to me to - I commented out 
  # RewriteBase /

in .htaccess and that did it for me - although i had to change all the links back to the original manually.

I haven't have time to troubleshoot why and what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out # RewriteBase / in .htaccess file.

if you placed the drupal files in sub folder  you need to add the 
RewriteBase /subfoldername in .htaccess file.